# What is the best practice for determining when a Canvas has been resized?

Tags: java, awt

Ok so I've been working on a graphing calculator for quite some time and early on in the project I implemented a somewhat robust window listener. Or should I say I built a robust window listener to handle updating local variables whenever the window size changed. What I basically did was this...

```
/*
canvas, canvasWidth, canvasHeight and refreshGrid() are all local to this class
*/
private class resizeCatch extends Thread{
    private boolean refreshOnStop = false;
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            if(canvasWidth != canvas.getWidth() || canvasHeight != canvas.getHeight()){
                canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
                canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
                refreshOnStop = true;
            }else if(refreshOnStop && canvasWidth == canvas.getWidth() && canvasHeight == canvas.getHeight()){
                refreshOnStop = false;
                refreshGrid();
            }
            try{Thread.sleep(100);} catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

I start this `Thread` when my `Plotter` object is instantiated and all it does is check the canvas's size and compare it to it's internal variables. When there's a difference update the variables, trigger an update to happen and when the difference(s) cease update the graphical side of things and continue listening for a change.

**I understand that this is a common practice.**

However I've been generalizing my `Plotter` window, I've made it more deployable and it doesn't necessarily have to manage it's own window anymore which is why I felt like it was time to kick this nasty eye sore to the curb! I still however have the issue with when to refresh the graphics... The obvious answer is when the canvas changes size but **how do I know?**

Ideally somewhere buried in the manuals (*oh and believe me I've read the manuals thoroughly these last few months...*) there lies some kind of WindowEventListener or ContainerListener that has a ResizeEvent or some kind of colloquial jargon I'm not familiar with. However I can not find anything!

While the idea of having extraneous `Thread` class's nested in my program with the infamous **while(true)** doing the dirty work of something as mundane as re-sizing components titillates me (**NOT**) I have to find some sort of alternative. So that kind of brings me back to the root of my question. What is the proper way to listen for and trigger a response to the dimensions of a container changing and if there are no *right ways* what practices have you put together that are lightweight, manageable and reasonable?

I've been able to ignore this for almost half a year now and as I near the finish of my program this is something I desperately want to get rid of. Please extend a helping hand :)

Comment: What's wrong with a [ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html)?

Comment: and with Thread.sleep(100); in latest JRE version is everything ..... too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so giant hat tip to [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) for pointing out the `ComponentListener` to me. Which while taking some time worked perfectly and exactly how I wanted. I know this question baffles a lot of people so I'll be a bit more verbose then most tutorials and explain the few simple steps to integrate a ComponentListener for the resizing of a window.

**Step One: Import the correct libraries**

```
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
```

**Step Two: Implement the listener to your class**

```
public class Plotter extends GCanvas implements ComponentListener{
```

**Step Three: Add your `Object` to the `ComponentListener`**

```
this.addComponentListener(this);
```

**Step Four: Override the following methods**

```
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e){
    //do whatever you want upon size change
}

public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e){
    //do whatever you want upon visibility change
}

public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e){
    //do whatever you want upon location change
}

public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e){
    //do whatever you want upon visibility change
}
```

That's pretty much it. Once these tools are in place you're in business! Enjoy :)

Comment: Sorry I like to use a lot of white space when formatting my code. It's not that uncommon :/

Comment: Yeah I didn't have the site too much in mind when it comes to posting my own code. Thanks for the pointer though and I'll keep it in mind :) oh and I was going to update them both anyway! You saved me about 8 seconds! Much appreciated.